# The make procedure of cmake in multi dependences situation

Tags: cmake, makefile

I have such a CMakeLists.txt which come from [DLoopDetector](https://github.com/dorian3d/DLoopDetector). I clear some unimportant part

I am confusing about the make procedure. The demo_brief target depends on DBoW2 and DLib, which was added as external project by ExternalProject_Add. The confusing part is that when `make`, the DLib will first build and the CMakeLists.txt seems conduct again and find_package(DLib) work as well as `message("DBoW2_LIBS: ${DBoW2_LIBS}") ;message("DLib_LIBS: ${DLib_LIBS}")` print correctly. DBoW2 build next and the CMakeLists.txt scan again. And finally, demo_brief target is built.

I don't know why the CMakeLists.txt will scan three times:

1. the first time, find_package(DBoW2) and find_package(DLib) failed
2. the secode time, find_package(DLib) work (after DLib was been built)
3. the third time, both find_package(DBoW2) and find_package(DLib) work after DBoW2 was been built

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(DLoopDetector)
include(ExternalProject)

option(BUILD_DemoBRIEF  "Build demo application with BRIEF features" ON)

set(HDRS
  include/DLoopDetector/DLoopDetector.h         include/DLoopDetector/TemplatedLoopDetector.h)

set(DEPENDENCY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dependencies)
set(DEPENDENCY_INSTALL_DIR ${DEPENDENCY_DIR}/install)
set(DEPENDENCY_CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})
if(DEFINED OpenCV_DIR)
    set(DEPENDENCY_CMAKE_ARGS ${DEPENDENCY_CMAKE_ARGS} -DOpenCV_DIR=${OpenCV_DIR})
endif()

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

macro(GetDependency name other_dependency)
  find_package(${name} QUIET
    PATHS ${DEPENDENCY_INSTALL_DIR})
  if(${${name}_FOUND})
    message("${name} library found, using it from the system")
    include_directories(${${name}_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_custom_target(${name}_dep)
  else(${${name}_FOUND})
    message("${name} library not found in the system, it will be downloaded on build")
    option(DOWNLOAD_${name}_dependency "Download ${name} dependency" ON)
    if(${DOWNLOAD_${name}_dependency})
      if(NOT ${other_dependency})
        set(dependency ${other_dependency}_dep)
      endif()
      ExternalProject_Add(${name}
        PREFIX ${DEPENDENCY_DIR}
        # GIT_REPOSITORY http://github.com/dorian3d/${name}
        # GIT_TAG master
        SOURCE_DIR /home/linzy5/MyProject/DBow2-learning/${name}
        INSTALL_DIR ${DEPENDENCY_INSTALL_DIR}
        CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<INSTALL_DIR> ${DEPENDENCY_CMAKE_ARGS}
        DEPENDS ${dependency})
      add_custom_target(${name}_dep ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} DEPENDS ${name})
    else()
      message(SEND_ERROR "Please, activate DOWNLOAD_${name}_dependency option or download manually")
    endif(${DOWNLOAD_${name}_dependency})
  endif(${${name}_FOUND})
endmacro(GetDependency)

GetDependency(DLib "")
GetDependency(DBoW2 DLib)
add_custom_target(Dependencies ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} DEPENDS DBoW2_dep DLib_dep)

include_directories(include/DLoopDetector/)


message("DBoW2_LIBS: ${DBoW2_LIBS}")
message("DLib_LIBS: ${DLib_LIBS}")
if(BUILD_DemoBRIEF)
  add_executable(demo_brief demo/demo_brief.cpp)
  add_dependencies(demo_brief DLib_dep DBoW2_dep)
  target_link_libraries(demo_brief ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${DLib_LIBS} ${DBoW2_LIBS})
  target_include_directories(demo_brief PUBLIC ${DLib_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${DBoW2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  set_target_properties(demo_brief PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 11)
endif(BUILD_DemoBRIEF)


configure_file(src/DLoopDetector.cmake.in
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/DLoopDetectorConfig.cmake" @ONLY)

install(DIRECTORY include/DLoopDetector DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include)
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/DLoopDetectorConfig.cmake"
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/${PROJECT_NAME})
install(FILES "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/DLoopDetectorConfig.cmake" 
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/cmake/DLoopDetector/)
install(DIRECTORY ${DEPENDENCY_INSTALL_DIR}/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX} OPTIONAL)
```

CMake always seems difficult to me especially when building system depends on multiple subprojects or dependences. How do I capture the essence of cmake?